# Calculate time blocked within a timerange with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a list of products produced or processes finished like this one:

| Name | Timestamp Start | Timestamp Stop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | 2021-01-01 15:15:00 | 2021-01-01 15:37:00 |
| Product 1 | 2021-01-01 15:30:00 | 2021-01-01 15:55:00 |
| Product 1 | 2021-01-02 15:05:00 | 2021-01-02 15:22:00 |
| Product 1 | 2021-01-03 15:45:00 | 2021-01-03 15:55:00 |
| ... | ... | ... |

What I want to do is to calculate the amount of time where no product/process happened in a given timeframe, for example from 15:00 to 16:00 and, to be more specific, each day.
The output could be "amount of idle minutes/time where nothing happened" or "percentage of idle time".

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
df = pd.read_csv('example_data.csv')

# generate list of products
listOfProducts = df['NAME'].drop_duplicates().tolist()

# define timeframe for each day
startTime = datetime.time(15, 0)
stopTime = datetime.time(16, 0)

# define daterange to look for
startDay = datetime(2021, 1, 1)
stopDay = datetime(2021,1, 5)


# do it for  every product
for i in listOfProducts:

    # filter dataframe by product
    df_product = df[df['NAME'] == i]
    
    # sort dataframe by start
    df_product  = df_product.sort_values(by='started')

    # ... how to proceed?
```

The wanted output should look like this or similiar:

| Day | Time idle |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 00:20:00 |
| 2021-02-01 | 00:43:00 |
| 2021-03-01 | 00:50:00 |
| ... | ... |

Here are some notes that are important:

- Timeranges of products can overlap between each other, in this case they should only "count once"
- Timeranges of products can overlap the borders (15:00 or 16:00 in this case), in this case the time within the borders should be counted

I struggle to implement it in a pandas-way, because this border-cases prevent me from adding up Timedeltas.
In the past, I solved this issue by iterating row by row from here and adding the minutes or seconds. But I'm sure there is a more pandas-way, maybe with the .groupby() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input data:

```
>>> df
        Name               Start                Stop
0  Product 1 2021-01-01 14:49:00 2021-01-01 15:04:00  # OK (overlap 4')
1  Product 1 2021-01-01 15:15:00 2021-01-01 15:37:00  # OK
2  Product 1 2021-01-01 15:30:00 2021-01-01 15:55:00  # OK
3  Product 1 2021-01-02 15:05:00 2021-01-02 15:22:00  # OK
4  Product 1 2021-01-03 15:45:00 2021-01-03 15:55:00  # OK
5  Product 1 2021-01-03 15:51:00 2021-01-03 16:23:00  # OK (overlap 9')
6  Product 1 2021-01-04 14:28:00 2021-01-04 17:12:00  # OK (overlap 60')
7  Product 1 2021-01-05 11:46:00 2021-01-05 13:40:00  # Out of bounds
8  Product 1 2021-01-05 17:20:00 2021-01-05 19:11:00  # Out of bounds
```

First, remove data out of bounds (7 & 8):

```
import datetime

START = datetime.time(15)
STOP = datetime.time(16)

df1 = df.loc[(df["Start"].dt.floor(freq="H").dt.time <= START)
              & (START <= df["Stop"].dt.floor(freq="H").dt.time),
             ["Start", "Stop"]]
```

Extract the minute of `Start` and `Stop` datetime. If the process began before 15:00, set to 0 because we want only keep overlap part. If the process ended after 16:00, set the minute to 59.

```
import numpy as np

df1["m1"] = np.where(df1["Start"].dt.time > START, 
                     df1["Start"].sub(df1["Start"].dt.floor(freq="H"))
                                                  .dt.seconds // 60, 0)

df1["m2"] = np.where(df1["Stop"].dt.time < STOP,
                     df1["Stop"].sub(df1["Stop"].dt.floor(freq="H"))
                                                .dt.seconds // 60, 59)
```

```
>>> df1
                Start                Stop  m1  m2
0 2021-01-01 14:49:00 2021-01-01 15:04:00   0   4
1 2021-01-01 15:15:00 2021-01-01 15:37:00  15  37
2 2021-01-01 15:30:00 2021-01-01 15:55:00  30  55
3 2021-01-02 15:05:00 2021-01-02 15:22:00   5  22
4 2021-01-03 15:45:00 2021-01-03 15:55:00  45  55
5 2021-01-03 15:51:00 2021-01-03 16:23:00  51  59
6 2021-01-04 14:28:00 2021-01-04 17:12:00   0  59
```

Create an empty table `len(df1)x60'` to store process usage:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(0, index=df1.index, columns=pd.RangeIndex(60))
```

Fill the `out` dataframe:

```
for idx, (i1, i2) in df1[["m1", "m2"]].iterrows():
    out.loc[idx, i1:i2] = 1
```

```
>>> out
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   ...  53  54  55  56  57  58  59
0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  # 4'
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   1   1  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
6   1   1   1   1   1   1   1  ...   1   1   1   1   1   1   1  # full hour

[7 rows x 60 columns]
```

Finally, compute the idle minutes:

```
>>> 60 - (out.groupby(df1["Start"].dt.date).sum() & 1).sum(axis="columns")
Start
2021-01-01    22
2021-01-02    42
2021-01-03    50
2021-01-04     0
dtype: int64
```

**Note**: you have to determine if the `Stop` datetime is closed or not.